# Run a Unix shell command on every EMR / Yarn node

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn, emr

I want to install a Python module on every node in an Amazon EMR cluster. It looks like the obvious way to do this is to ssh in to every node and install it at the command line. I was looking at YARN as a way of running the same JAR file on every node in a cluster, but YARN's "jar" command seems to run on the local system.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [bootstrap](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticMapReduce/latest/DeveloperGuide/emr-plan-bootstrap.html) to install 3rd party software on every EMR node while bringing up the cluster.

If you are using command line, you can pass shell script that is saved in s3 as part of bootstrap action.

```
aws emr create-cluster --name "Test cluster" --ami-version 3.3 \
--use-default-roles --ec2-attributes KeyName=myKey \
--applications Name=Hue Name=Hive Name=Pig \
--instance-count 5 --instance-type m3.xlarge \
--bootstrap-action Path="s3://elasticmapreduce/bootstrap-actions/download.sh"
```

If you are using web interface

- Create shell script to download necessary software
- Go to `advanced options` and as part of `General Cluster Settings` you can specify Bootstrap Actions
- Every time you clone the cluster, those actions will be preserved and make sure bootstrap is done while bringing up the cluster.

Comment: This is the approach recommended by Amazon, it turns out. It's great for initial startup, but it doesn't work well for adding new features on the fly. Thanks for the detailed `aws emr` command.

Answer (score 4):

Here's one potential way to run a script across all nodes *after* the EMR cluster has been created.

```
yarn node -list 2>/dev/null \
    | sed -n "s/^\(ip[^:]*\):.*/\1/p" \
    | xargs -t -I{} \
    ssh -i ~/.ssh/yourkey.pem hadoop@{} \
    "pip install package"
```

A few notes on what's happening here:

- the `yarn node -list` step lists all nodes (use the `--states` option to restrict this)
- the `sed` step parses that list to get just the node names
- if needed, add `-o StrictHostKeyChecking=no` to ssh to disable host key checking
- if needed, add `-P n` to xargs to limit this to `n` nodes at a time
- this requires the SSH private key to be present on the current node

Comment: I have also tested scp to all workers node.                                         
  yarn node -list 2>/dev/null \
    | sed -n "s/^\(ip[^:]*\):.*/\1/p" \
    | xargs -t -I{} \
    scp -i ~/yourkey.pem  ~/your-folder/* hadoop@{}:/home/hadoop/your-folder/

Answer (score 1):

YARN has a code example named distributed-shell which can the work you said. But it is a bit heavy, you can use puppet which can do install and configure software in the cluster. Of course, it can also run the unix shell command or install python module.

For more details, please see http://puppetlabs.com

Comment: Hi. Could you please provide a pointer to the distribute-shell so that I can accept your answer? Thanks.

Comment: Here is the [source code](https://github.com/apache/hadoop-common/tree/trunk/hadoop-yarn-project/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-applications/hadoop-yarn-applications-distributedshell/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/yarn/applications/distributedshell) and [example](https://github.com/apache/hadoop-common/tree/trunk/hadoop-yarn-project/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-applications/hadoop-yarn-applications-distributedshell/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/yarn/applications/distributedshell).

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty ugly but i'm using a pair of `run-if` bootstrap actions with `instance.isMaster=true` and `instance.isMaster=false` to run my command on all nodes:

```
--bootstrap-action \
Path=s3://elasticmapreduce/bootstrap-actions/run-if,Args=["instance.isMaster=true","sudo pip install sklearn"] \ 
Path=s3://elasticmapreduce/bootstrap-actions/run-if,Args=["instance.isMaster=false","sudo pip install sklearn"]
```